# mplayer plays clip of previous file when loading new file

Tags: mplayer

Loading an audio file in mplayer, pausing it, then loading a new file results in a brief bit of the initial audio file being played before playing the new file.

To replicate the issue:

1. Run mplayer in slave mode from a terminal: `mplayer -slave -quiet /path/to/audio.file`
2. mplayer is now accepting [input commands](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/tech/slave.txt). Type `pause` and hit Enter to pause the playback. Then type `loadfile /path/to/new/audio.file` and hit Enter to load a new audio file.

In the [input commands](http://www.mplayerhq.hu/DOCS/tech/slave.txt) documentation, there is a tip...

> Try using something like...
>
> - pausing_keep_force pt_step 1
> - get_property pause
>
> to switch to the next file. It avoids audio playback starting to play 
>   the old file for a short time before switching to the new one.

I have tried using the documentation tip, but either it's not working or I don't understand how to use it correctly. **How do I prevent this small bit of the old audio file from playing?**

I have compiled mplayer from trunk of their source tree and the issue persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it took some mplayer source browsing to figure out that the 'tip' was a little incomplete.

I was able to prevent the short clip of playback by appending to the mplayer play_tree and stepping to the next track, rather than creating a whole new play_tree. FYI: The 'play_tree' is just a data structure used by mplayer to organize the currently loaded tracks.

After loading an initial track, proper loading of a new track can be accomplished using the following commands...

- `loadfile /path/to/new/audio.file 1`
- `pt_step 1`

The first line tells mplayer to load the new file and the trailing 1 (which could be replaced by any non-zero value), tells mplayer to append the file to the existing play_tree. The second line tells mplayer to step forward 1 track in the play_tree.

If the number at the end of the first line is omitted or 0, a new play_tree will be created and the new file will automatically be played, but preceded by a small piece of the previous track.

Hope this helps someone else.